# React 17 issue - "'React' is declared but its value is never read"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier

Recently I have upgraded to React 17 and it's started showing "'React' is declared but its value is never read" error in all the files. As per the [React Doc](https://ru.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#eslint) I don't need to import the React anymore. It's working if I remove it but I have concerns here! Mine was a big project.. i don't want to touch each and every file. Is there a way that i get of this problem without removing React from import statement.
I'm using typescript and ESLint.

Comment: The page you linked recommends using `npx react-codemod update-react-imports` to clean up the imports automatically for you

Comment: Well, the alternative is to touch every file and add an eslint-disable-X comment for each `React` import. I suggest you go the route of removing it since it's not necessary.

Comment: my concern is; I don't want to change the existing code and just trying to skip the rule, skip the lint as well. I could use  `npx react-codemod update-react-imports`  but it updated all the files

Comment: able to resolve this issue by adding `DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true` in `.env` file at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

Add `DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true` in your .env file, and don't forget to stop/start your project

Comment: Please provide more details how this solves the problem.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html